# Converting prototype Ajax function to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototype

How would I convert the following prototype-based js code to jQuery? I'm stripping prototype out of an existing site that is having jQuery integrated into it and there are just a few pieces of code like this that were dependent on prototype:

```
function updateJobSubCategory(blockToUpdate, ParentID){
      var url = '/resource/ajax/selectCategories.cfm';
      var params =  'multiple=1&ParentID=' +  ParentID + '&selectedList=' + CategoryList($('SubCategoryIDs'));
      $(blockToUpdate).innerHTML = "<div>Loading...</div>";

      var ajax = new Ajax.Updater(
          {success: blockToUpdate},
          url,
          {method: 'post', parameters: params}
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function updateJobSubCategory(blockToUpdate, ParentID)
{
    var url = '/resource/ajax/selectCategories.cfm';
    var params =  'multiple=1&ParentID=' +  ParentID + '&selectedList=' + CategoryList(jQuery('SubCategoryIDs'));
    jQuery("#"+blockToUpdate).html("<div>Loading...</div>");     
    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        evalScripts: true,
        url: url,
        data: params,     
        success: function (data, textStatus){              
            jQuery("#"+blockToUpdate).html(data);
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the answer of Minesh Patel. In jQuery 1.8 on the jqXHR object (returned by $.ajax) `success` is replaced by `done`, `error` with `fail` and `complete` by `always`. If you want to be up to date you should use `done` instead of success.